# PS Unexpected Token

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the following PowerShell script:

```powershell
$server=MACHINE_NAME

if (Test-Path \\$server\c$\test.txt) {$server"/yes`n" | out-file c:\log.txt -append}
else {$server"/no`n" |out-file c:\log.txt -append}
```

When I try to run it, I get:

> Unexpected token '/yes ' in expression or statement. At line:2 char:44
>
> An empty pipe element is not allowed. At line:2 char:53
>
> Unexpected token '/no ' in expression or statement. At line:3 char:13
>
> An empty pipe element is not allowed. At line:3 char:21

I anticipate this is something simple that I am not seeing. I am pretty new to PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a variable be adjacent to a string literal; that is invalid syntax.

If you want to combine the two strings, use either the `+` operator:

```powershell
$server + "/yes`n"
```

or variable interpolation:

```powershell
"$server/yes`n"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$server=MACHINE_NAME
if(Test-Path ("\\{0}\c$\test.txt" -f $server)) 
{
    ("{0}/yes`n" -f $server) | out-file "c:\log.txt" -append
}
else
{
    ("{0}/no`n" -f $server) | out-file "c:\log.txt" -append
}
```